# Set-StrictMode bug powershell 7 or normal behavior

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Hopefully you can explain this to me. I have a script to scan AD for computer objects. I just started working with powershell 7.

Part of the script is as following:

```bsh
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"

$adComputerCollection  = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -like "*Windows Server*" }
```

With powershell 7 it gives me the a error the following error:

```bsh
Get-ADComputer: The 'Get-ADComputer' command was found in the module 'ActiveDirectory', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module ActiveDirectory'.
```

ok so no problem I just add the import-module and my script is as following:

```bsh
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"

Import-Module "ActiveDirectory"

$adComputerCollection  = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -like "*Windows Server*" }
```

Then I get the following error while importing the module activeDirectory:

```bsh
Get-PSSession: The remote session with the name WinPSCompatSession  is not available.
```

Is this normal behavior. With powershell 5.1 i dont have this problem. I can fix this by setting the strict-Mode after I get the Ad collection. Can someone explain this behavior to me?

My psversiontable is:

```bsh
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activedirectory module is loaded in "remote" PSSession to localhost called WinPSCompatSession. The module is not actually running PS 7, but 5.1.

This is probably why you see the error.